Error: SocksProxyAgent is not a constructor when trying to use socks-proxy-agent to proxy to a tor website
I am trying to connect to tor through socks-proxy-agent but it throws an error called:
SocksProxyAgent is not a constructor
I tried ChatGPT and also read somethings online and tried implementing but nothing worked, this should have opened a window with the HTML response.
here is the code:
const { app, BrowserWindow, dialog } = require('electron');
const axios = require('axios');
const SocksProxyAgent = require('socks-proxy-agent');


async function checkTorConnection() {
    const proxyOptions = 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050';
    const agent = new SocksProxyAgent(proxyOptions);

    try {
        await axios.get('http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onion', { httpsAgent: agent });
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}

function createWindow() {
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    });

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');
}

app.on('ready', async () => {
    try {
        await checkTorConnection();
        createWindow();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to Tor:', error.message);
        dialog.showErrorBox('Connection Error', 'Connection to TOR failed. Please contact admin for help.');
        app.quit();
    }
});

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit();
    }
});


